# TextView setText with non empty string crashes with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException (related to AccessibilityNodeInfo)

Tags: android, textview, androidx

I have following code in my app:

```
fun updateFilterInfo(showing: Int, total: Int) {
    binding?.tvFilterLvl1?.text = "$showing / $total" // problematic line in AddItemFragment class - Line 562 
}
```

`tvFilterLvl1` is a simple `TextView`, I'm using android x and kotlin and I think this exception should never happen. I can't reprocude this issue. Anyone else ever had this problem? Any ideas how to solve it?

I'm getting following exception in my app:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpansRec(SpannableStringBuilder.java:935)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:866)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getSpans(SpannableStringBuilder.java:836)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.<init>(SpannableStringBuilder.java:80)
at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.subSequence(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1183)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfo.setText(AccessibilityNodeInfo.java:2517)
at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(TextView.java:12009)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:7939)
at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfoInternal(View.java:7898)
at android.view.View.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(View.java:7883)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:146)
at android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecord.setSource(AccessibilityRecord.java:119)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(View.java:7835)
at android.widget.TextView.onInitializeAccessibilityEventInternal(TextView.java:11990)
at android.view.View.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View.java:7823)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUncheckedInternal(View.java:7685)
at android.view.View.sendAccessibilityEventUnchecked(View.java:7670)
at android.view.View$SendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent.run(View.java:27420)
at android.view.View$SendViewStateChangedAccessibilityEvent.runOrPost(View.java:27453)
at android.view.View.notifyViewAccessibilityStateChangedIfNeeded(View.java:11856)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6027)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5847)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5804)
at com.my.app.AddItemFragment.a(SourceFile:562)
...
```

Comment: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=-1 
 generate when you try to get access of a invalid position of array . This is not a problem of TextView setText method.

Comment: check the stacktrace and you will see that it seems to be a bug in the `TextView`. I'm not accessing any index nor am I setting an invalid text. And the crash happens inside the `TextView`. If you think I'm it's my problem, tell me where it is inside this simple code: `binding?.tvFilterLvl1?.text = "$showing / $total"`

Comment: Are you using any custom styles, fonts, or attributes in your theme? Also, just for the "sake of having fun with Android", what happens if you pass the string already composed (instead of that inline Kotlin)?

Answer (score 0):

try to set `android:importantForAccessibility="no"` in the xml file for this view